# Error llamado de procedimientos almacenados desde entity framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Bueno cree 2 procedimientos almacenados el cual llenan un campo en especifico, a lo cual desde sql server si los llena y no marca ningún error:

Procedimiento 1:

```
USE [ProductoTerminado]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_BuscarOrdenesSinEstado]    Script Date: 30/06/2022 12:42:43 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BuscarOrdenesSinEstado]
as 
 UPDATE OrdenesPT
    set CveCompuesta = Id, OT = ''
    where Posicion = 0 and CveCompuesta is null
```

Procedimiento 2:

```
USE [ProductoTerminado]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_BuscarOrdenesConEstado]    Script Date: 30/06/2022 12:42:37 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BuscarOrdenesConEstado]
AS
UPDATE OrdenesPT
        SET CveCompuesta = LTRIM(RTRIM(OT)+RTRIM(Pedido)+RTRIM(Posicion))
        where Posicion != 0 and CveCompuesta is null
```

entonces los cree así en entity framework:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Actualizacion/BusquedaActualizacionSinEstado")]
        public IEnumerable BusquedaActualizacionSinEstado()
        {
            using (ProductoTerminadoContext bd = new ProductoTerminadoContext())
            {
                
                var resultado = bd.OrdenesPt.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE SP_BuscarOrdenesSinEstado").ToList();
                yield return 0;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Actualizacion/BusquedaActualizacionConEstado")]
        public IEnumerable BusquedaActualizacionConEstado()
        {
            using (ProductoTerminadoContext bd = new ProductoTerminadoContext())
            {

                var resultado = bd.OrdenesPt.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE SP_BuscarOrdenesConEstado").ToList();
                yield return 0;
            }
        }
```

Si los ejecuto desde postman me marca el siguiente error ya sea uno u otro, lo curioso es que aun así mandando el error si lo actualiza entonces no se cual es el inconveniente del porque lo hace así:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql'
```

y su clase es esta:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ot { get; set; }
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    public int Posicion { get; set; }
    public string Sociedad { get; set; }
    public string Numero_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public string CodigoMaterial { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public double Cantidad { get; set; }
    public double Importe { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Salida { get; set; }
    public string SalidaEmp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaSalidaEmp { get; set; }
    public string Mes { get; set; }
    public string Ejercicio { get; set; }
    public string Dia { get; set; }
    public string CveCompuesta { get; set; }
```

Comment: NAda que ver, pero es la segunda pregunta que veo que hacees lo mismo, y yo por lo menos no termino de comprender el porque, haces yield return en una funcion dentro de un controller el cual claramente no vas a iterar. Puede que tengas una confusion de conceptos?  El error es que esta tratando de convertir la salida de tu SP al dbcontext correspondiente de donde hiciste la llamada, cosa que obviamente no puede.. pero claro.. ya ejecuto el SP...

Comment: Que podria hacer para realizarlo, ya que si le quito el **.ToList()**  no hace el update del SP